# TypeError: #<...> is not a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer, active-attr

I cannot figure out this issue, even if it does not seem complicated...

I want to make a form to send emails in my rails app but this one does not work. I receive the following error:

`TypeError in MessagesController#create`:
`#<Message content: "test", email: "test@test.fr", name: "test"> is not a symbol`

Error occurs in: `app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:10:in 'create'`

1.here is my `messages_controller`:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    if @message.valid?
      Messenger.send(@message).deliver
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

end
```

1. the form `new.html.erb`:

   ```
   <%= form_for @message do |f| %>
       <%= f.text_field :name %>
       <%= f.text_field :email %>
       <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 5 %>
   <%= f.submit "Send Message" %>
   <% end %>
   ```
2. the `Message` model built using `ActiveAttr`:

   ```
   class Message
     include ActiveAttr::Model

     attribute :name
     attribute :email
     attribute :content
   end
   ```
3. My `Messenger` mailer:

   ```
   class Messenger < ActionMailer::Base
     default :from => "test@test.com"

     def send(message)
       mail(:to => "test@test.com", :subject => "test")
     end

   end
   ```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I guess the error is in the send.html.erb in Messenger mailer. Can you share the code of send.html.erb?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

replace `send` with a different method name because it conflicts with the one defined in ruby.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar TypeError using the send method, because it was expecting a symbol and I passed in something else. I fixed it by doing something like

```
send(some_variable) if some_variable == Symbol
```

However, it looks like you're trying to send mail and you're using an old way to do it. Rails 4.1.8 has a new way to do so here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html